# Distribute pictures in Word 2010 across multiple pages

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I want to take a random number of pictures that are all pasted onto the first "Page" of a Word document and distribute them across multiple pages in the same document, 2 per page. So if there were 10 pictures on the first page, 1 and 2 would stay on the first page. 3 and 4 would be moved to the second (3 at the top, 4 at the bottom). 5 and 6 would move to the third page, etc...

And to make things a little more complicated, a string with the image number has to be placed at the bottom of each image. And each image needs to be positioned and sized based on if they are horizontal/vertical, horizontal/horizontal, vertical/vertical, or vertical/horizontal.

I've got the code written, but the added breaks aren't showing up where I thought they would.

Anyone feel like reviewing some code? P.S. I'm very new to VBA so please don't be too harsh. Constructive is always welcome though.

```
Private Sub FormatPics()
    PictCount = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count

    For PictCurrn = 1 To PictCount
        ' If this is an odd pictcurrn, then we're at the first
        ' image for the page. So get the H and V (or N) for the
        ' pictures that belong on the page
        If (PictCurrn = 1) Or ((PictCurrn Mod 2) = 1) Then
            With ActiveDocument.Shapes(PictCurrn)
                Pic1L = .Left
                Pic1T = .Top
                Pic1W = .Width
                Pic1H = .Height
                If Pic1W > Pic1H Then
                    Pic1X = "H"
                Else
                    Pic1X = "V"
                End If
            End With

            If PictCurrn < PictCount Then
                With ActiveDocument.Shapes(PictCurrn + 1)
                    Pic2L = .Left
                    Pic2T = .Top
                    Pic2W = .Width
                    Pic2H = .Height
                    If Pic2W > Pic2H Then
                        Pic2X = "H"
                    Else
                        Pic2X = "V"
                    End If
                End With
            Else
                Pic2X = "N"
            End If

            ' Next we set the picture format for the current 2 pictures

            ' Picture Format 1
            If (Pic1X = "H") And (Pic2X = "H") Then
                PictFormat = 1
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(0)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(0)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)

                Pic2Left = CentimetersToPoints(0)
                Pic2Top = CentimetersToPoints(15.04)
                Pic2Width = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
                Pic2Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
            End If

            ' Picture Format 2
            If (Pic1X = "V") And (Pic2X = "H") Then
                PictFormat = 2
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.83)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(-0.89)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)

                Pic2Left = CentimetersToPoints(1.05)
                Pic2Top = CentimetersToPoints(15.41)
                Pic2Width = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
                Pic2Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
            End If

            ' Picture Format 3
            If (Pic1X = "H") And (Pic2X = "V") Then
                PictFormat = 3
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(0.42)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(-0.69)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)

                Pic2Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.83)
                Pic2Top = CentimetersToPoints(10.43)
                Pic2Width = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
                Pic2Height = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
            End If

            ' Picture Format 4
            If (Pic1X = "V") And (Pic2X = "V") Then
                PictFormat = 4
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.83)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(-0.89)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(10.1)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(13.3)

                Pic2Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.83)
                Pic2Top = CentimetersToPoints(13.09)
                Pic2Width = CentimetersToPoints(10.1)
                Pic2Height = CentimetersToPoints(13.3)
            End If

            ' Picture Format 5
            If (Pic1X = "H") And (Pic2X = "N") Then
                PictFormat = 5
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(0.42)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(-0.69)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
            End If

            ' Picture Format 6
            If (Pic1X = "V") And (Pic2X = "N") Then
                PictFormat = 6
                Pic1Left = CentimetersToPoints(2.83)
                Pic1Top = CentimetersToPoints(-0.89)
                Pic1Width = CentimetersToPoints(10.21)
                Pic1Height = CentimetersToPoints(15.3)
            End If
        End If

        ' Create the index sring
        PageString = CStr(PictCurrn)
        While Len(PageString) < 3
            PageString = "0" & PageString
        Wend
        PageString = "[" & PageString & "]"

        With ActiveDocument.Shapes(PictCurrn)
            ' Handle Picture1
            If (PictCurrn = 1) Then
                ' Select the picture
                .Select

                ' Move it to the pre-determined position
                .Left = Pic1Left
                .Top = Pic1Top
                .Width = Pic1Width
                .Height = Pic1Height

                ' Add the PageString tag
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeParagraph
                Selection.InsertAfter PageString
            End If

            If (PictCurrn = 2) And (PictFormat < 5) Then
                ' Select the picture
                .Select

                ' Move it to the pre-determined position
                .Left = Pic2Left
                .Top = Pic2Top
                .Width = Pic2Width
                .Height = Pic2Height

                ' Add the PageString tag
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeParagraph
                Selection.InsertAfter PageString

                ' It's the job of the second picture to add the page break after itself
                Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            End If

            If (PictCurrn > 2) And ((PictCurrn Mod 2) = 1) Then
                ' First picture for new page
                .Select
                Selection.Cut
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.Paste

                .Left = Pic1Left
                .Top = Pic1Top
                .Width = Pic1Width
                .Height = Pic1Height

                ' Add the PageString tag
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeParagraph
                Selection.InsertAfter PageString
            End If

            If (PictCurrn > 2) And ((PictCurrn Mod 2) = 0) And (PictFormat < 5) Then
                ' Second picture for new page
                .Select
                Selection.Cut
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.Paste

                .Left = Pic2Left
                .Top = Pic2Top
                .Width = Pic2Width
                .Height = Pic2Height

                ' Add the PageString tag
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
                Selection.TypeParagraph
                Selection.InsertAfter PageString

                ' It's the job of the second picture to add the page break after itself
                Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            End If
        End With
    Next PictCurrn
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm happy to look at this, but do you have a document with said pics already in it to save stuffing around trying to get some that will work? You can upload it to dropbox or the like.